# printing String output is empty

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming , when `I cout << str` outside the loop , it prints nothing and when `cout << str[0] << str[1]` it prints the `char` in this position and also length of `str` outside of the loop is `0`, what is the reason for that behavior.

**Note**: I tried to use concatenate `str+= s[i];` and it's working in this case , I can `cout << str;`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    int z = k;
    string s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string str;
    int repeated = n-k;
    for(int i{};i<n;++i){
        if(k > 0){      //distinct
        str[i] = s[i];
            k--;
            //cout << str[i];
        }else if(k==0 && repeated >0){    //repeated
            str[i] = str[i-z];
            repeated--;
            //cout << str[i];
        }
    }
    cout << str;
        //cout << str[0] << str[1] << str[2] << str[3] << str[4] ;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string str;` is an empty string with size `0` and nothing in your code changes that.

Accessing any element but `str[0]` invokes undefined behavior. There is no `str[i]` for `i > 0`.

To append to a string you can use `+` or `std::string::append`.

Comment: thanks for the answer , this means accessing any element in str doesn't change it's size and i have to append.

Comment: @logan_92 exactly. `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`s `operator[]` is a weird exception, but other than that I don't know any standard container that implicity grows its size on element access, you either have to `resize` or `push_back` or `append` or `+`